# How can I say "gooey"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe a specific type of cake which is very popular in Sweden (kladdkaka). It contains no baking powder, and therefore the consistency remains almost viscous, kind of like fudge. In English I think "gooey" suits. What can I say in Esperanto?

Comment: I guess I'd add that in the middle it can be very gooey and the ends are mostly fully baked. It's great that someone is asking! 

Answer (score 7):

I think the word *glueca* is what you're looking for. The PIV defines it as follows:

> **glueca.** Prezentanta la ecojn de gluo: *rezino estas glueca; gluecaj manoj de infano.*

However, if you want to emphasize viscosity (which might not make sense for a cake that, while sticky, is still solid), you could use *viscoza* or *viskeca*:

> **viskoz/a** ☐ Malfacile fluanta, siropeca alteniĝema, kiel la fruktosuko de visko. *Sin. viskeca*.

Comment: Other people also suggested glueca. For some reason I'd prefer not to use it for food (at least not food I like!) since it is linked to glue. You guys are probably right though, I let my associations decide too much when it comes to food!

Comment: I would not say _glueca_ too, when referred to food I like. It seems more a word I would use to complain about food.